# VB.NET console application to modify iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication .config file

Tags: vb.net, console

I made a little console application to help me with remapping client certificates to my webserver.  However, when I try to run the application it is giving me an error of:

Unhandled exception at 0x00920309 in CertMapping.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

It's a pretty basic console app:

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.Administration

Module Module1
Sub main(ByVal cmdArgs() As String)
    Dim WebSite As String = Nothing
    Dim UserName As String = Nothing
    Dim Password As String = Nothing
    Dim Base64EncodedCertData As String = Nothing
    Dim switch As String, arg As String

    For Each Str As String In cmdArgs
        switch = Split(Str, ":").First
        arg = Split(Str, ":").Last
        Select Case switch
            Case "/Web"
                WebSite = arg
            Case "/User"
                UserName = arg
            Case "/Pwd"
                Password = arg
            Case "/Cert"
                If arg = "mySecretCode" Then
                    Base64EncodedCertData = "ServerCertGoesHere"
                Else
                    Base64EncodedCertData = arg
                End If
        End Select
    Next

    Using serverManager As New ServerManager
        Dim config As Configuration = serverManager.GetWebConfiguration(WebSite.ToString)

        Dim iisClientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication")
        iisClientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection("enabled") = True
        iisClientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection("oneToOneCertificateMappingsEnabled") = True

        Dim oneToOneMappingsCollection As ConfigurationElementCollection = iisClientCertificateMappingAuthenticationSection.GetCollection("oneToOneMappings")
        Dim addElement As ConfigurationElement = oneToOneMappingsCollection.CreateElement("add")
        addElement.SetMetadata("lockItem", True)
        addElement("enabled") = True
        addElement("userName") = UserName.ToString
        addElement("password") = Password.ToString
        addElement("certificate") = Base64EncodedCertData.ToString
        oneToOneMappingsCollection.Add(addElement)

        Dim accessSection As ConfigurationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/access", WebSite.ToString)
        accessSection("sslFlags") = "Ssl, SslNegotiateCert"

        serverManager.CommitChanges()
    End Using
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: are you sure the user that are impersonating have access. This is something i found that may help you as well, http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/iisClientCertificateMappingAuthentication#006

Comment: why don't you debug it to discover the offending line?